# Numeric coincidence between Rava and Tosefta?

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-nazir

[Nazir 13b](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.13b.3):

> Rava asks: If one said: I am hereby a nazirite after ***twenty*** days, and I am hereby a nazirite from now for one ***one hundred*** days, what is the halakha?

The [next page](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.14a.4) resolves the question:

> Tosefta (2:5): If one says: I am hereby a nazirite after ***twenty*** days, and I am hereby a nazirite from now for ***one hundred*** days, then he...

If Rava is aware of the Tosefta, why does he ask the question?

If he is not aware of it, how come he uses the exact same sample numbers?

My guess is that the numbers were made identical by the editors - is this reasonable?